# How to read char array from binary file in C?

Tags: arrays, c, file, binary, fwrite

I am trying to write from a struct array into a binary file and read back its contents. Someone suggested I use "fwrite" with sizeof and it has worked, partially. This is my code:

```
            structObject structArray[50]; 
            structArray[0] = newObject // Not shown here but a new element is added to the main array from user input

            structObject read[1]; //This array is for reading only
            
            FILE* fp = fopen("storeStructs.bin", "wb");
            fwrite(structArray, sizeof(structObject), 1, fp);
            fflush(structArray);
            fclose(fp);
            fp = fopen("storeStructs.bin", "rb");
            fread(read, sizeof(structObject), 1, fp);

            printf("\n\n The name is: %s\n\n", read[0].name);
            //name is a char array
```

This works for integers but not char arrays.

EDIT: Don't know how I didn't realize but I was using %d instead of %s. This didn't fix the issue however, now it simply returns nothing.

Comment: `fflush(structArray);` looks wrong. Is `structObject` an alias of `FILE`?

Comment: Printing char array via `%d` invokes *undefined behavior*. You should use `%s` if the char array is null-terminated.

Comment: It is confusing to use library names like read for variables.

Comment: You should check 1. Whether each calls of file operating functions succeeds. 2. The contents of the saved file (for example `od -Ax -t x1 storeStructs.bin`) Also please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you need to give us the definition of *structObject*. Also what do you have doing `printf("\n\n The name is: %s\n\n", newObject.name);`?

Comment: Is `read[0].name` really an array (like `char name[1024];`), not a pointer (like `char* name;`)?

Comment: what do you have printing `newObject.name`(e.g. `printf("\n\n The name is: %s\n\n", newObject.name);`?